# is there a log/historic of all the file locks?

Tags: rhel, logs

I recently had a server (Red Hat) that experienced a few minutes long slowness (involving mysql but anyway). After some investigations, I'm wondering if another background process (`sa1` maybe?) could have locked some of mysql files for a while, leading to mysql not being able to get locks on  them, hence waiting and getting slow.

Is there a way, like a log file or whatever, to see which process requested a read or write lock on any file?

I'm not looking for a "snapshot" or current locked files, because slowness is now over, so it wouldn't appear in a "current locked files" list.

Comment: Have you considered that the perceived slowness could depend on something else, such as swapping, some process doing a lot of disk access, or if the MySQL server was on another system, that the network got congested for a while?

Comment: Yes I did, I still have other things to check too but even out of this issue, such lock log could be helpful anytime in the future evne if not involved in this specific issue